# Concept of old and new values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to keep a log about the fields of certain table when it gets updated and store this new as well as the old values in history_logs table and this should be dynamic.

I am new to Postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at an extension called "table_log": http://andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/100-Log-Table-Changes-in-PostgreSQL-with-tablelog.html

Comment: It's an extension written in C, but it's use is completely transparent to the programmer. Consider composing real sentences.